# Angular Routing with Children issue

Tags: angular

For lack of better words to explain, lemme show some code of what I've done, and what I want:

Here's my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [   
    { path: '', component: LandingComponent,
    { path: 'myroute', loadChildren: './myroute/myroute.module#MyrouteModule' }
];
```

Here's my `mymodule/mymodule.routing.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent },
    { path: 'subroute', loadChildren: './subroute/subroute.module#SubrouteModule' },
  ] }
];
```

There's a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` appropriately within the `/myroute/nav.component.ts`

Then lastly, there's this `mymodule/subroute/subroute.routing.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: SubrouteComponent },
    { path: 'subroute', component: SubrouteComponent }, 
];
```

So here's a mental picture of the correct expectation:

`localhost/` matches `LandingComponent`

`localhost/myroute/` matches `WelcomeComponent`

`localhost/myroute/subroute/` matches `SubrouteComponent`

With the above in mind, should I request,

`localhost/subroute`

it matches the `SubrouteComponent` directly, however **fails** to inject it in a router outlet, which is expected.

The match is as a result of matching both the `''` of the `mymodule.routing.ts` and `subroute.routing.ts` `''`, therefore the `SubrouteComponent` kinda leaks through.

Now, the question. Is there a way I could let the `/subroute` be matched only when the incoming URL matches a specification?

Is that what the `URLMatcher` is for? How would it be accomplished?

Comment: I suppose my first question is, if you're controlling the [routerLink] and know the correct paths, how would one like that slip through?

Comment: Of course, I set the `[routerLink]`s myself, so paths are almost always correct. I mistakenly entered a seemingly wrong URL, which I was expecting (which was wrong expectation) the `**` route to kick in. Since the component showing only won't make any use of the navigation, I was hoping i could limit clients from even hitting those routes, and have them redirect to somewhere right, or show notfound.